# TIN Creation from 3D Contour File

Tags: qgis, 3d, contour, dxf, tin

I'm currently trying to import a 3D contour file into a QGIS project.

How can I export the DXF file from Microstation with height information?

I already have imported it to the QGIS project but can not create a TIN because the height info is missing.

I'm using QGIS Lisboa 1.8.0

Comment: I've had a problem like this with DXF contour layers. In the DXF the elevation values (the "z" values) are contained in the xyz triplets that form the vertices of the lines. When you convert from DXF to SHP GDAL/OGR doesn't save the z-values as attributes. Is this the problem you have? N.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import a 3D DXF file into QGIS with z information as attribute value?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90568/how-to-import-a-3d-dxf-file-into-qgis-with-z-information-as-attribute-value)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Interpolation plugin.  It is not turned on by default so click Plugins -> Manage Plugins and check the Interpolation Plugin box.  Once activated access the plugin by clicking Raster -> Interpolation -> Interpolation.

From the plugin's menu there is a checkbox that will allow you to use the Z value of your layer as the elevation source rather than a value from the attribute table.