# DXF (points and lines) in QGIS - Doesn't import z coordinates

Tags: qgis, dem, dxf

Trying to get to grips with QGIS, coming from a MapInfo and Civil3D background.

I have a DXF file with points (X,Y,Z) and lines.  I want to open this in QGIS and use the interpolate plugin to create my DEM.

When I open the DXF I assign a coordinate system, however the Z attributes don't seem to come across and so the interpolate function fails.

I could be doing something wrong on a very basic level - any pointers on where to start?

Comment: CAD files are always a pain, they're not structured as one would want when using GIS software. Presumably your points are blocks in CAD, and if you have access to Civil3D you can use [this guide](http://synergiscadblog.com/2013/03/26/how-to-convert-autocad-blocks-to-a-civil-3d-point-file-in-10-steps/) to extract coordinates to a csv, which you then can import to QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

First forget about QGIS when playing with 3D, QGIS is not really there yet. If extracting vertices is enough or the lines are isolines (contours - constant elevation) then it is possible to use approach with free tools as explained here:

[Importing 3D DXF file into QGIS with z information as attribute value?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90568/how-to-import-a-3d-dxf-file-into-qgis-with-z-information-as-attribute-value)

The problem is when the lines in DXF have actually vertices in different elevations. In that case GRASS skip these lines when running v.to.rast. I think the only way in that case is to densify vertices on these particular lines to some needed minimum distance and extract them as points - v.to.points (dmax = your wanted minimum resolution value).

So in this case the process in open source **GRASS** (comes together with QGIS OSGeo4W installation):

**v.in.dxf** - to import contours including z dimension

**v.to.points** (dmax=) - to have all as points - while making sure lines become enough (dmax) dense points

**v.to.rast** (use=z) - convert dense points to raster

**r.surf.contour** - to linearly interpolate the rest of the surface (DEM) between points (lines)

In this case it is also possible to use other r.surf.* or interpolate from points v.surf.* or use v.out.ascii to export points to ascii x|y|z format and use any other software for surface interpolation