# Importing DXF - Polylines with elevation data

Tags: qgis, elevation, dxf

When importing a DXF file (containing 3D contour data) to QGIS, none of the various methods described elsewhere are retaining elevation data as an attribute.

e.g. DXF2SHP, GRASS v.in.dxf, opening natively as a vector file in QGIS etc. DXF2XYZ is not applicable as the file does not contain point data.

The DXF file contains polylines with elevation data only. All line objects are imported successfuly and there are no errors.  Are there any other utilities?

Answer (score 1):

If you import the dxf file using v.in.dxf you can get the elevations, as it's explained in the answer to this question, [Importing 3D DXF file into QGIS with z information as attribute value?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90568/importing-3d-dxf-file-into-qgis-with-z-information-as-attribute-value). One thing you need to keep in mind is the use of the v.in.dxf tool from the processing toolbox depending of the version you're using, see this question, [v.in.dxf not working properly in GRASS toolbox in QGIS 2.18.11](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252331/v-in-dxf-not-working-properly-in-grass-toolbox-in-qgis-2-18-11/252394#252394)