# Have you all solve importing Z point from dxf to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, references

I have read all the answer about importing dxf to QGIS, but I still not understand yet.

Does anyone have a video link (youtube or another) that show me step by step to export dxf with Z point to QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into importing "3D DXF" or opening 3D DXF as a search term. You can also search for "extract elevation" if that is you goal.
Below are some links:

[Importing 3D DXF file into QGIS with z information as attribute value?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90568/importing-3d-dxf-file-into-qgis-with-z-information-as-attribute-value)

https://pigrecoinfinito.wordpress.com/2016/02/25/qgis-dxf-3d-da-shp-2d3d/